# How to call Scala's Queue.enqueue(iter: Iterable[B])?

Tags: scala

In Scala's `immutable.Queue`, there are two methods both named `enqueue`:

```
  /** Creates a new queue with element added at the end
   *  of the old queue.
   *
   *  @param  elem        the element to insert
   */
  def enqueue[B >: A](elem: B) = new Queue(elem :: in, out)

  /** Returns a new queue with all elements provided by an `Iterable` object
   *  added at the end of the queue.
   *
   *  The elements are prepended in the order they are given out by the
   *  iterator.
   *
   *  @param  iter        an iterable object
   */
  def enqueue[B >: A](iter: Iterable[B]) =
    new Queue(iter.toList reverse_::: in, out)
```

I don't know how to resolve the ambiguity and call the second one. Here's what I have tried:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_07).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import collection.immutable.Queue
import collection.immutable.Queue

scala> val q: Queue[Int] = Queue(1,2,3)
q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3)

scala> q.enqueue(Iterable(4))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Any] = Queue(1, 2, 3, List(4))

scala> q.enqueue[Int](Iterable(4))
<console>:10: error: overloaded method value enqueue with alternatives:
  (iter: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int])scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] <and>
  (elem: Int)scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int]
 cannot be applied to (Iterable[Int])
              q.enqueue[Int](Iterable(4))
                       ^
```

Comment: I gotta' say, it looks like a bug to me, but maybe there's something I'm not getting.

Comment: @RandallSchulz IMHO, both things: you did miss something, but that's really a bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tricky, tricky!

I [created a ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6981) about it. You see, you have been misled by types!

```
scala> q.enqueue(scala.collection.Iterable(4))
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Any] = Queue(1, 2, 3, List(4))

scala> q.enqueue(scala.collection.immutable.Iterable(4))
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The `Iterable` imported by default is the `scala.collection.Iterable`, which can be either mutable or immutable, but the immutable queue requires the *immutable* `Iterable` instead.

Comment: @DanielCSobral (Long time, Daniel!) What are you going to request in the ticket? Documentation clarification??

Comment: @RandallSchulz I think the API should be changed. There's no reason to require an immutable iterable.

Comment: I see, thanks! In addition, I haven't noticed that Seq, IndexedSeq, Iterable, and Traversable are not immutable by default. I assumed that everything is immutable like List, Stream, and Vector.

Comment: What's ironic is that the `scala.collection.Whatever` types have only the immutable complement of members, since that's essentially what's in common between the mutable and immutable counterparts of any given collection class implements.

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.13 deprecates the overload in favor of `enqueueAll`.

Meanwhile, an easier way to get around would be to explicitly mention the types.

```
  val q = Queue[Vector[Int]]()

  val uQ: Queue[Vector[Int]] = q.enqueue(Vector(6))
```